# Parental Control - Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, websites, url, parental-controls

I'm searching for a Parental Control on a Ubuntu 22.04 but not only website and contents restrictions. I would like to access to the list of website visited. And I'd like to restrict APP installation, limiting per age.
I searched a long time but I found only solutions that limit the time spent in Ubuntu use.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `And I'd like to restrict APP installation, limiting per age` - Do you know that only administrator accounts have sudo access, and other accounts cannot install apps?

Comment: You can use a parental control browser addon https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/block-and-unblock-websites-parental-controls-firef?redirectslug=Parental+controls&redirectlocale=en-US